# Why did I getting a (# # #) in result?

Tags: printing, lisp, common-lisp

I try to solve a task and try to convert this Parameter:

```
(DEFPARAMETER AUSSAGEN '(
                         (THE OFFICE IS EAST OF THE HALLWAY)                                       
                         (THE KITCHEN IS NORTH OF THE OFFICE)                                      
                         (THE GARDEN IS WEST OF THE BEDROOM)                                       
                         (THE OFFICE IS WEST OF THE GARDEN)                                        
                         (THE BATHROOM IS NORTH OF THE GARDEN)                                     
                         (THE BEDROOM IS SOUTH OF THE LAVATORY)                                    
                         (THE BATHROOM IS WEST OF THE LAVATORY)                                    
                         (THE KITCHEN IS WEST OF THE BATHROOM)                                     
                         (THE KITCHEN IS EAST OF THE STUDIO)                                       
                         (THE HALLWAY IS SOUTH OF THE STUDIO)))
```

to this List:

```
((HALLWAY EAST OFFICE) (OFFICE WEST HALLWAY) 
(OFFICE NORTH KITCHEN) (KITCHEN SOUTH OFFICE)
(BEDROOM WEST GARDEN) (GARDEN EAST BEDROOM) 
(GARDEN WEST OFFICE) (OFFICE EAST GARDEN)
(GARDEN NORTH BATHROOM) (BATHROOM SOUTH GARDEN) 
(LAVATORY SOUTH BEDROOM) (BEDROOM NORTH LAVATORY)
(LAVATORY WEST BATHROOM) (BATHROOM EAST LAVATORY) 
(BATHROOM WEST KITCHEN) (KITCHEN EAST BATHROOM)
(STUDIO EAST KITCHEN) (KITCHEN WEST STUDIO) 
(STUDIO SOUTH HALLWAY) (HALLWAY NORTH STUDIO))
```

This is my Code:

```
(DEFUN WB-GEN (AUSS)
  (COND ((NULL AUSS))
        (T  (LIST (FirstList(REVERSE (CAR AUSS)))(SecondList (CAR AUSS))(WB-GEN (CDR AUSS)))))
)

(Defun FirstList (AUSS)
  (LIST (CAR AUSS) (CADDDR AUSS) (CADDR(CDDDR AUSS)))
)

(DEFUN SecondList (AUSS)
  (LIST (CADR AUSS) (let ((x(CADDDR AUSS)))(COND 
                                            ((EQL x 'NORTH)'SOUTH)
                                            ((EQL x 'EAST)'WEST)
                                            ((EQL x 'SOUTH)'NORTH)
                                            ((EQL x 'WEST)'EAST))) (CAR (LAST AUSS)))
```

But I don't know why I get in result something like this list (# # #)

Complete result from my code: `((HALLWAY EAST OFFICE) (OFFICE WEST HALLWAY) ((OFFICE NORTH KITCHEN) (KITCHEN SOUTH OFFICE) ((BEDROOM WEST GARDEN) (GARDEN EAST BEDROOM) (# # #))))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch of things that make your code hard to read:

- it is not properly formatted
- there are way too many *cadddddddddr* functions

The formatting is easy to fix using your editor.

Getting rid of *cadddddddddr* is done by either

- using functions like `first`, `second`, ...
- or by using list patterns in `loop` and `destructuring-bind`

Easier:

```
CL-USER 8 > (flet ((opposite (direction)
                     (case direction
                       (above 'below)
                       (below 'above))))
              (loop for (nil what1 nil direction nil nil what2)
                    in '((the bath is above of the kitchen)
                         (the roof is above of the bath))
                    collect (list what2 direction what1)
                    collect (list what1 (opposite direction) what2)))
((KITCHEN ABOVE BATH)
 (BATH BELOW KITCHEN)
 (BATH ABOVE ROOF)
 (ROOF BELOW BATH))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an artifact of the printer.  The `#` signify omissions in the output.  You most likely have `*print-level*` active at some low value.  If you inspect your result, it will be revealed to be complete.

This behaviour is intended to make REPL interaction with large outputs manageable.

Of course, it shows that your output is not correct, as it is deeply nested.